# Does Agarest: Generations of War 2 carry on from the true end or normal end of the previous game?

Tags: agarest-war

I completed *Agarest: Generations of War Zero*, and now going to start playing *Agarest: Generations of War* before playing *Agarest: Generations of War 2*. However, I'm wondering if the sequel carries on from the true end or the normal end.

I ask this, as when I played *Atelier Meruru* there was a spoiler of the true ending of *Atelier Totori*:

> Totori's mother isn't dead, as Totori tells Meruru that her mother just showed up. Considering the true end requirements for Totori, which requires defeating Evil Face who Totori's mother set out to kill, it would make sense.

If *Agarest: Generations of War 2* carries on from the previous game's true ending, then I would plan on replaying *Agarest: Generations of War Zero* with Digest Mode since it will always have the true end (I don't plan on doing that right now cause I have to play though all of *Zero* again).

**Which *Agarest: Generations of War* ending does *Agarest: Generations of War 2* carry on from: The true end, or the normal end?**

Answer (score 1):

Agarest 2 follows neither ending. It takes place in an alternate reality from the first two games so, aside from a few nods and references to them, is a stand-alone story wise.

Comment: I can confirm this. From [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E6%88%A6%E8%A8%982), "物語の舞台となる世界や神話や種族などといった世界観こそは前2作と共通しているが、パラレルワールドであるために時系列的な繋がりはなく、一部の設定に差異が認められる部分が存在する。" which is basically saying that it takes place in a parallel world, thus the timeline isn't connected to the previous works.